Concentration inequality of the covariance matrix
In the high-dimensional statistics field, we always use concentration inequalities to get the convergence rate with high probability. when I read lecture notes about graphical models, I find that the concentration inequalities about $\|\Sigma-\hat{\Sigma}\|_{max}$ often appear where $\|A\|_{max}=\underset{i,j}{\max}|X_{ij}|$.
My questions:

What does the frequent appearance of the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\max}$ mean, and what intuition is hidden behind it?

I want to know about the concentration inequality of covariance matrices with other norms, for example, spectral norm $\|\Sigma-\hat{\Sigma}\|_2$. To the best of your knowledge, What is the best result of this concentration inequality?



Addressing your question 1, $~\Sigma~$ is a statistic of the generative ("true") distribution. $\hat{~\Sigma~}$ is a statistic of the model distribution. $\left\Vert  ~\Sigma-\hat{~\Sigma~} \right\Vert_\textrm{max}$ is a model-fit metric in the graphical model community.
See Dempster 1972 Covariance Selection for a discussion addressing multivariate normal distributions. On the top of page 162, Dempster discusses measures of fit.  A "forward" procedure is outlined, where complexity is added to a model until the model fit is acceptable.  A "backward" procedure is outlined too, where complexity is removed until a model fit would become unacceptable.
